# How can i make my close button works on screens with different sizes?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why my .closebtn doesn't work on screens with other size and how i can fix it?
HTML

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeSection('figurative1')">&times;</a>
```

CSS

```
.closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 39px;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: rgb(250, 3, 3);
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  #figurative1 .closebtn,  #painting1 .closebtn,  #portret1 .closebtn,  #stilllife1 
  .closebtn,  #landscape1 .closebtn  {
    top: 5px;
    right: 8px;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: rgb(250, 3, 3);
    text-decoration: none;
    position: absolute;
  }
}
```

JS

```
function openSection(id) {
    let element = document.getElementById(id);
    element.style.width = "100%";
    showSlides(1, element);
}

function closeSection(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = "0%";
}
```

https://codepen.io/tatarusetskaya/pen/XWpzNZa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other elements where drawn over your button, if you make the `z-index` of your button higher it becomes clickable again.

```css
.closebtn {
  z-index: 99
}
```

https://codepen.io/leelenaleee/pen/NWjEYpP

Comment: and can you help me with similary problem, please - why my menu doesn't open, when screen size is 768*1024? It's because of z-index too?

Comment: I dont know, works fine for me with that width, what you can do to check if its an z index issue are 2 things: first thing you can check if is your mousepointer changing to a hand indicating it can click, second thing is you can use your dev console to see all the area the elements are taking so you can check if another element is using the space over the menu button

Comment: it works, when i turn on  (ctrl+shift+m) toggle device toolbar. 
In other situation - it's grey circle instead mousepointer and it doesn't work in this case (on some screens, and 0n 768*1024 too)

Answer (score 0):

Give `z-index:1` to the `.closebtn`.

Check this out: [CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/ozikputrajarwo/pen/QWvJmdb)